# How to transform query in sql for query in rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do i transform this query with left join and where does not exist for query in rails, i am using rails 6.0.3

This query must collect all items from tableB that do not have a code present and the expiration date less than the date that will be passed by parameter

```
query_for_delete_codes = "
SELECT expires_at, code FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON code = tableB.created_code
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM tableB WHERE tableB.created_code = code
)
AND expires_at < '#{date_limit}'
"
```

Comment: can you use `find_by_sql`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell your model names so I called the model for tableA A and tableB B. Perhaps something like this works for you:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bs, foreign_key: :created_code, primary_key: 'code'
end

class B < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a, foreign_key: :code, primary_key: 'created_code'
end

A.select(:expires_at, :code)
  .left_joins(:bs)
  .where.not(bs: { created_code: code })
  .where('expires_at < ?', date_limit)
```